# Random Forest - Need help understanding the rfcv function

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, model-selection

My current data set has about 900 records & 10 features. I am trying to use random forest to classify some data. My current model is terribly over fitting the data hence I am trying to use the rfcv function. I am having some trouble understanding the output of this function.

Here is some sample code

```
data(fgl, package="MASS")
tst <- rfcv(trainx = fgl[,-10], trainy = fgl[,10], scale = "log", step=0.7)
```

I can print some output from this but I am not sure how to interpret this?

```
        9         6         4         3         2         1 
0.2102804 0.2196262 0.2429907 0.2523364 0.3551402 0.5607477
```

I also have the log of the importance function

```
   MeanDecreaseGini
RI        23.358203
Na        15.901377
Mg        25.923452
Al        24.587295
Si        12.586816
K         13.731823
Ca        19.680839
Ba        14.206922
Fe         6.774196
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rfcv function creates multiple models based on the number of predictors and the "step" argument (default = 0.5). In your case you began with 9 predictors with step = 0.7 which corresponds to the first row in your output

- first value = 9,
- second value = round(9(0.7)) = 6,
- third value = round(6(0.7)) = 4, and so on.

So the first row of the output is just the number of predictors used in each model. The second row in your output is the cross-validation error of each of the models. It becomes clear that as the number of predictors are reduced the error generally increases, but the difference between using 9 predictors and using 6 predictors is low which suggests the 6 predictor model is about as good as the 9 predictor model.